# Expected value to equal: [Function wrap] - how to mock it?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, wrapper, jestjs

Like in title - I'm running JEST unit tests for my Vue.js app, and I want to test the equality (`.toEqual()`) of the variable that represents `[Function wrap]` (it's created thanks to `axios.create()`) - how to mock such value?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing functions is kind-of difficult. I'd recommend to use `.toBeDefined()` instead. But personally I would not check the return value of `axios.create()`.